# How to create a switching function in shell which turns ON on one call and OFF on another?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

for example :i need a function which infinitely prints a character on first call and stops on the next call.
what i have tried is creating a function that has a stopping condition and recalled it like below.
`spin 1` 
starts the function and 
`spin 0` 
when called again just doesnt do anything leaving the function infinitely running.
the function is as below

```sh
spin()
{
  spinner=( "██" "████" "██████" "████████" "██████████" "████████████" "██████████████" "████████████████" "                ")
  i=0
  while :;
  do
    if [[ $1 -eq 0 ]]
    then
      break
    else
      echo -ne "\r${spinner[i%9]}"
      sleep 0.2
      i=$((i+1))
    fi
  done
}
spin $1
```

could someone suggest any workaround.

i cannot use pgrep or grep and kill the script as it compulsorily  displays 'Killed' message in the terminal.

Comment: Each time you call a function it runs in it's own space. But you could make your function's stop condition included in the loop, like the presence or absence of a file in a specific directory. When you call spin 0 it creates the said file so the loop will end. Just an example though.

Comment: This is pretty common with scripts that are started by init. Whenever the process/script is called with "start", it creates a temporary file and the file is deleted when the process/script is called with "stop" or it exits on its own. 
If the file exists, any other invocations of the script with "start" fail with an error. 

You can use the same logic or you can just check if the script is running and kill it. :)

`PID=`pgrep <script_name`; if [ $PID != "" ]; then kill -9 $PID fi`

Comment: i had tried using kill command too but it shows a killed message which i dont want to be displayed.i tried pointing the output to a null but it turns out it prints to the terminal no matter what.so cant use the kill -9 in my case